# If the subject is singular why do we say "would have" instead of "would has"?

Tags: modal-verbs, conjugations

[image]

> Would the English student _____ easy access to synonyms, antonyms and the origin of the new words if a good dictionary _____ on his cellphone?

1. has/was installed
2. has/installed
3. have/were installed
4. had/had been installed

The answer of this question is number three. Is number three correct or not? However, the student is singular, so shouldn’t we use *has* instead of *have*?

Comment: Hi Sina, please do not ask homework questions unless you have done your own research first. https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask Your book surely has a name for this grammar form which will help you do research on the topic. Then, you probably won't even have a question.

Comment: Conjugated verb forms are *He **likes** coffee* and *They **like** coffee*, but we only modify the *auxiliary* verb (TO DO) when asking the questions ***Does** he like coffee?* and ***Do** they like coffee?* Where in both cases the verb TO LIKE is a "bare infinitive" (which doesn't include the "infinitive marker" ***to***). It's the same principle with *Would he like coffee? / Would they like coffee?*, or *Would the English student [**have** something]*. Note that ***would*** is a "defective" verb, that doesn't change form depending on singular or plural subject *(**He / They** would help)*.